# Php upload and bandwidth/traffic question

Tags: php, file-upload

I have set upload limit to 3M in php.ini. If someone uploads a file that is 50 mb, then does the upload stop when it hits 3Mb or does it continue until the upload is complete, then reads the filesize and deletes the file?

Comment: as soon as it reaches 3 it will stop. you should test it

Comment: @Ibu: What server are you using? Can't reproduce your results on Apache :(

Comment: apache *itself* has a limit on the post size. Could that be the case?

Comment: @Salman A: Indeed it does, but the default is "no limit" and frankly, I have yet to see a different value in practice. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Apache as your web server, then PHP doesn't get a chance to start until the request completes. Thus, the upload limit only comes into action *after* the whole upload finishes. Apache *first* receives the *entire* request, and *only then* does it invoke the appropriate handler (in this case, PHP). Since there is no server-side mechanism to abort a HTTP request in progress *and* return a response, you'll need to wait until the whole request is complete.

So, to answer your question: **NO**, the upload will go through in full; PHP's internal logic will check the uploaded file size, see that it's larger than the limit, and then fail immediately with an error. Your PHP script will **not** get a chance to run, so don't rely on runtime checks - they won't be executed at all.

Comment: Then someone could really abuse you, and ruin your bandwidth monthly qouta or ruin you financially by uploading large files non stop so you waste traffic right? that you have to pay for 0.10 cents for me using AWS. how do you best prevent them from uploading large files above the limit?

Comment: @BlackBrother: yes, that's (at least theoretically) possible. I don't know how to prevent that, except by blocking such abusive IP address. The documentation for Apache's configuration directive `LimitRequestBody` suggests that it might be useful here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody